# Best way to save data structure in Electron app

Tags: electron

I am building an app using Electron. In this app, I am building a data structure using JSON or an simple object. My data structure looks like this:

`{ items: [ { id:1, name:'football' }, { id:2, name:'soccer ball' }, { id:3, name:'basketball' } ] }`

I want to save this JSON or object because I want to load the data the next time the application starts.

Now the question is if I use LocalForage.js and users remove thier browser's data, will the saved data of my application be removed too? or I can be sure the saved data in my app persist for ever...?

Note: LocalForage.js wraps indexedDB for local storage in browsers and if user clears the browser's data all the  data will be removed.

Comment: I just use Node's "fs" to write to a file in appdata

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best way" to store data. I use [electron-store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store) to store user preferences and app state in JSON format that I want to restore. It works very well and is easy to implement.

> Now the question is if I use LocalForage.js and users remove thier
> browser's data, will the saved data of my application be removed too?
> or I can be sure the saved data in my app persist for ever...?

Electron is for making desktop apps, There is no "browser". If you save data to the application support directory, a user will be able to dig in there and remove it. You can be "clever" and store data under an obscure name or in a different place but a determined user will be able to find and remove it.

Or perhaps I misunderstand what  you are asking.